# Changing Tensorflow MNIST code with interactive session into session

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I have been learning tensorflow, and I have tried to change the code on the documentation from being run on an interactive session to being run in a regular session, so that I can run the python file containing the code from command line. The relevant tensorflow code is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html

Here is my code:

```
import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
def train():
    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
    for i in range(1000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

def test():
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(train())
    sess.run(test())
```

However, I am getting error message when I try to run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow_mnist.py", line 15, in <module>
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1267, in run
    _run_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2763, in _run_using_default_session
    session.run(operation, feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 345, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 419, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
     [[Node: MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_Placeholder_0, Variable)]]
Caused by op u'MatMul', defined at:
  File "tensorflow_mnist.py", line 10, in <module>
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 781, in matmul
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 600, in _mat_mul
    transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 633, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1710, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 988, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I have no idea what is causing this problem; most likely it is an incorrect usage of the session. Could someone give me some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are just two things you need to change to make this work:

1. Initialise the variables before running the first training steps.

   ```
   init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
   init_op.run()
   for i in range(1000):
       # …
   ```

   This will fix the first error you are seeing, and is an important first step in any TensorFlow program that uses variables.
2. Inline the bodies of `train()` and `eval()` in the `with tf.Session() as sess:` block. Your `eval()` function uses local variables from `train()` so the code is not valid Python as written. (Note that the `sess.run()` around `train()` and `eval()` is incorrect too—those functions don't have a return value, so this is equivalent to calling `sess.run(None)`, which will raise an error.)

Comment: Thanks! After doing your suggestion, it all worked. Just curious, are 
init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
init_op.run()

and session.run(init_op) equivalent to each other?

Comment: If you're inside a `with tf.Session():` or `with sess.as_default():`, or a using a `tf.InteractiveSession`, they're equivalent. Otherwise, only the `session.run(init_op)` version will work.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works:

```
import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:

    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 784])
    y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 10])
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
    y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    init_op.run()
    cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)
    for i in range(1000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))
```

Comment: Note that it's faster to create your graph *before* creating the session.  (i.e., moving `x = ..` through `init_op = ...` to outside of the `with tf.Session` block.